# What's a correct expression for professions in which you do a lot of sitting?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I'm a native Dutch speaker writing a short English piece on sitting professions, sitting positions and whether these positions are back friendly. In Dutch we would just write these words together, but this seems wrong in English. What are proper terms for sitting profession, sitting position and back friendly?

Comment: That would be a "desk job".

Comment: You can run words together in English, but you are more likely to keep the spaces, as in *back-friendly sitting positions*.  It reminds me of the British claim to excel at ["sitting-down sports"](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2184822/Olympics-2012-Cycling-rowing-equestrian-successes-Team-GB-brink-historic-gold-medal-haul.html) such as cycling, rowing, sailing and equestrian.

Comment: Hot Licks is right - also, a job in which one is paid to do mental labour is sometimes called a 'white-collar' job (as opposed to a job in which one does physical  labour, which is a 'blue-collar' job). White-collar jobs are very often 'desk jobs' and involve a lot of sitting down.

Comment: @HotLicks Driving commercial vehicles and working on a checkout are examples of "sitting" professions - neither are desk jobs.

Comment: @Mikaveli - I'll give you the driving, but in the US it's exceedingly rare for a checkout person (cashier) to be seated.

Comment: @HotLicks It might be uncommon in the US, but the world is rather larger than that. Besides, the examples were only to illustrate there are jobs where you're seated, but not at a desk.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A profession in which one sits for long periods is a *sedentary* profession, and a seated position might also be described as *sedentary*.

A back-friendly posture might be called *ergonomic*, but that sense is more of a marketing buzzword than a "proper" usage. I might just stick with *back-friendly* for that.

Comment: Welcome to ELU Malnormal, your answer would be more valuable if you cited a dictionary or other authoritative resource.

Comment: *Ergonomic* has been a successful marketing buzzword for long enough (a couple decades by my recollection) that it is widely understood in this sense.

Comment: Is it conventional here to regard dictionaries as authoritative? That's a little linguistically backwards, IMO

Answer (score 7):

I would say desk job indicates a job requiring sitting.  In terms of sitting position I would say do not slouch but sit up straight.  And in terms of back-friendly I would recommend good posture.

Comment: A limo driver sits, but you wouldn't describe that as a desk job, would you?

Answer (score 1):

*Sedentary* would describe a very inactive occupation. However, it doesn't specifically mean *sitting*.

*Posture* might work for sitting position... *Seated posture* to be more specific, but, again, it doesn't directly specifically mean *sitting*.

Comment: It sure does mean seated. Check a dictionary. It is the best word choice here; just what is asked for.

Comment: I stand corrected, it *does* mean seated. Thank you, Steven.

Comment: Also I don't see how *seated posture* doesn't directly specifically mean *sitting*.

Comment: @PatrickT From *sedentarius*, an adjective from *sedeo* ... which IMO means "I sit" even more than "I stay" -- anyway, sedentary doesn't 'sound uneducated' to me.

Comment: @ChrisW, you're right. Oops.